# RTNETLINK answers: Device or resource busy; ifup: failed to bring up wlxf4f26d13b2bd

Tags: linux, debian, wifi, network-interface

I'm trying to configure the network via /etc/network/interfaces here's my file:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug usb0
iface usb0 inet dhcp

# The wifi network interface
iface wlxf4f26d13b2bd inet manual 
    hwaddress ether 2a:bf:x9:53:38:9d
    wpa-driver nl80211
    wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

but when I try to activate the device with `ifup wlxf4f26d13b2bd` I get:

```
> RTNETLINK answers: Device or resource busy ifup: failed to bring up
> wlxf4f26d13b2bd
```

I'm not using NetworkManager.

This is the verbose output of ifup:

```
ifup -v wlxf4f26d13b2bd

ifup: configuring interface wlxf4f26d13b2bd=wlxf4f26d13b2bd (inet)
/bin/run-parts --exit-on-error --verbose /etc/network/if-pre-up.d
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/macchanger
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wireless-tools
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant
wpa_supplicant: terminating wpa_supplicant daemon via pidfile /run/wpa_supplicant.wlxf4f26d13b2bd.pid
Stopped /sbin/wpa_supplicant (pid 1568).
wpa_supplicant: removing /run/sendsigs.omit.d/wpasupplicant.wpa_supplicant.wlxf4f26d13b2bd.pid
wpa_supplicant: wait for wpa_cli to attach
wpa_supplicant: wpa-driver nl80211
wpa_supplicant: /sbin/wpa_supplicant -s -B -P /run/wpa_supplicant.wlxf4f26d13b2bd.pid -i wlxf4f26d13b2bd -W -D nl80211 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -C /run/wpa_supplicant
Starting /sbin/wpa_supplicant...
wpa_supplicant: creating sendsigs omission pidfile: /run/sendsigs.omit.d/wpasupplicant.wpa_supplicant.wlxf4f26d13b2bd.pid
wpa_supplicant: ctrl_interface socket located at /run/wpa_supplicant/wlxf4f26d13b2bd

/sbin/ip link set dev wlxf4f26d13b2bd address 2a:bf:x9:53:38:9d
RTNETLINK answers: Device or resource busy
ifup: failed to bring up wlxf4f26d13b2bd
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue. The problem was that it was trying to change the MAC address after the wpa_supplicant configuration; The order of commands in the file is not respected. The simple solution is either to set the mac address with `pre-up macchanger -m` inside the iface stanza or to invoke macchanger before wpa-supplicant.
Thanks!

Comment: Great! I was also having problems with wpa_supplicant while trying to change the hardware mac.